# Fraction reduction C program

Tags: c

Alright Guys, SO this was an homework assignment, however It's been submitted and I received a 78 :. My professor has yet to respond to my email of help  So here I am now.

The first part of the code is supposed to reduce fractions to their lowest form, and it works.. except when the greatest common denominator is above 10. This is an introduction to C class and I have very little to no experience with C and its specificities. Any help/guidance/ideas with the GCD issue..?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
int num;
int den;
int x;
int y;
int i;
int a;
int n;
int w;
int j;

printf("\n *************Question 1 *************** \n");
printf("Please enter the numerator: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("Please enter the denominator: ");
scanf("%d", &den);
printf("The fraction entered is: \n %d/%d \n", num, den );
if (num > den)
x=den;
else
    x=num;
for(i=x; i>=1; i--){
        if(num % i == 0 && den % i == 0){
                        printf("This fraction can be reduced! \n");
                num = num/i;
                den = den/i;
                    printf("The reduced fraction is %d/%d \n \n", num, den); break;}
        else
            printf("This fraction cannot be reduced any further \n");
                break;
}
printf("\n ***************Question 2****************** \n");
printf("Please enter a number and I will print the even squares up to your input   ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for ( w=1; w<=n; w++)
        if (w*w%2 == 0 && w*w <= n )
printf("%d \n", w*w);

printf("Question 5 test... please enter 10.3 then 5 then 6 ");
scanf("%d%f%d",&i,&x,&j);
printf("%d %f  %d \n",i,x,j);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You get a+1 for a) tell us it is homework and b) you have tried something. But please have another at indentation

Comment: Perhaps you lost much of the extra 22 percentage points due to the low legibility of your code. Never underestimate the importance of legibility. Also, you'd be better to name your variables more meaningfully and there's no commenting at all to indicate what your code is/should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `break` unconditionally in your reduction loop, so you never loop more than once. You shouldn't the `break` at the end of the loop, that means "whether we found the gcd, or we found a divisor that *doesn't* work, stop looking."

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right (the formatting makes the code hard to read), but either way it's breaking unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you! I found this out after hours of staring at the assignment. After removing my complete "else" statement my code works perfectly well. The else statement prevented my code from reiterating the loop. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that, in this code:

```
        else
            printf("This fraction cannot be reduced any further \n");
                break;
```

you intended to group the `break` with the `printf`:

```
        else
        {
            printf("This fraction cannot be reduced any further \n");
                break;
        }
```

However, either way is incorrect. As written, the first iteration of the loop will perform either the then-clause of the `if`, which reduces the fraction and exits the loop, or will perform the else-clause and then break (whether the `break` is grouped with the `printf` or not). Your intent is for the loop to continue if the first iteration does not reduce the fraction. To achieve this, the `else`, the `printf`, and the `break` should not be in the loop at all.

Instead, you should allow the loop to continue executing iterations until it completes either because the `break` in the then-clause terminates it with a successful reduction or because the controlling expression in the `for` statement ends the loop, when `i` reaches zero.

After the loop, you can test whether `i` is zero. This will tell you whether the loop ended because a reduction was performed (and the `break` was executed) or because the loop exhausted all the iterations. In the latter, case, you can print the message that the fraction cannot be reduced, if you desire to print such a message.

An important skill is to learn to debug problems like this by examining how the loop executes. You could do this either by stepping through the program in a debugger or insert `printf` statements to report what is happening in each iteration of the loop. This would have revealed that the loop executes only one iteration, regardless of the inputs.

Incidentally, there is a much better algorithm for reducing fractions than testing potential divisors until one is found. It is approximately 2300 years old and was described by Euclid in *Elements*, book (chapter) VII, propositions 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=x; i>1; i--)
{
    if(num % i == 0 && den % i == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if ( i > 1 )
{
    printf("This fraction can be reduced! \n");
    num = num/i;
    den = den/i;
    printf("The reduced fraction is %d/%d \n \n", num, den);
}
else
    printf("This fraction cannot be reduced any further \n");
```